# How to filter the data in a combobox based on a selection in another combobox infoPath 2010

Tags: infopath2010

I have two comboboxes in an infoPath 2010 form, one is the main office and the other is the sub office. Each combobox has has identifiers for example

Main Office : IE

Sub Office: IE1, IE2

So I want to hide all entries except for those that begin with IE when IE is selected in the Main Office

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use a SharePoint List to store those values then query it in data connections

Get the sub office values in the list using filters when Main Office contains IE.